# validation error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

May I know why my insert function will display the validation message first even i do not insert any data yet.once I enter the insert page,it display the validation message.i have try to move the form validation to the below of the if else statement,it do not show the validation message but it cannot submit the data to the database. below is my controller function.

```
 public function Insert_Result($Course_ID=null)
     {
         $this-load-helper('form');
         $this-load-library('form_validation');

         /* Model */
         $this-load-model('ResultEvaluation');

         /* Session */
         $session_data = $this-session-userdata('logged_in');
         $data['Ins_ID'] = $session_data['Ins_ID'];
         $this-session-set_userdata($data);

         /* Form Validation*/

         //$this-form_validation-set_rules('Course_ID', 'Course_ID', 'required');
         $this-form_validation-set_rules('Matric_No', 'Matric_No','required');
         $this-form_validation-set_rules('Student_Name', 'Student_Name', 'required');
         $this-form_validation-set_rules('Result_Mark_1', 'Result_Mark_1', 'required');
         $this-form_validation-set_rules('Result_Mark_2', 'Result_Mark_2', 'required');
         $this-form_validation-set_rules('Result_Mark_3', 'Result_Mark_3', 'required');
         $this-form_validation-set_rules('Result_Mark_4', 'Result_Mark_4', 'required');
         $this-form_validation-set_rules('Result_Mark_5', 'Result_Mark_5', 'required');

         if ($this-form_validation-run() === FALSE)
         {
             $data['results'] = $this-ResultEvaluation-get_record();
             $data['query'] = $this-ResultEvaluation-view($Course_ID);

             $this-load-view('templates/header');
             $this-load-view('Insert_Result', $data);
             $this-load-view('templates/footer');
         }
         else
         {
             $my_action = $this-input-post('submit');
             if ($my_action == 'Submit') 
             {
                 $this-ResultEvaluation-insert_record($Course_ID);
                 redirect('Result_Evaluation/Student_Result_List/'.$Course_ID,
 'refresh'); 
             }
         }        
         $my_action = $this-input-post('submit');
         if ($my_action == 'Cancel') 
         {
             redirect('Result_Evaluation/Student_Result_List/'.$Course_ID,
 'refresh');
         }

      }
```

Comment: ya,but it show when i enter the form.the validation should be pop out once i press the submit button if there are some error.

Comment: if ($this-form_validation-run() == FALSE)

Comment: corrected,but the validation still display once i enter the insert form.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help

```
public function index(){
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation'));
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('field_name', 'Text','trim|required');

            if($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE){

               // do something
            }else{
                // validation error
                redirect("to/your/controller");
                break;
            }
    }
```

for more information visit : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html